# Potree/Three.js measuring questions

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-clouds

Firstly, I'm newbie and non-native speak english, sorry.

In this moment, I work with multiple ( and differents ) point clouds loaded in the same page with the awesome Potree 1.4RC, but I want to read the height of a point cloud automatically, I mean, that reading all points of cloud and detect max dimension. I have worked with:

```
Var Potree.Measure areaMeasurement = new ( ) ;
areaMeasurement.addMarker (new THREE.Vector3 (0, 0 , 0)) ;
areaMeasurement.addMarker (new THREE.Vector3 ( -10 , 0 , 0 ) ) ;
viewer.measuringTool.addMeasurement ( areaMeasurement ) ;
```

But my points are predefined... my question is how can I do to obtain the maximum height or width of a PointCloud ( not bounding box )?

Otherwise, how can I obtain a spatial coordinate (p.e: Z) when I give the others (p.e.: X and Y) in Potree or Three.js? Would be possible auto detect this maximums and obtain her coordinates?

A lot of thanks,
Best regards.

Comment: Why is the bounding box of the points not acceptable?

Comment: Because in some cases, the point cloud has a dismatch orientation respect to bounding box. P.e.: If I want to measure cube width with little rotation, bounding box was created with diagonal vertex (bad measure), instead lateral points(good bounding box measure).

Comment: The bounding box provides a reasonable approximation. If the bounding sphere is also not acceptable, what is your definition of "maximum width".

Comment: Imagine that you want measure width of a rectangular table, I need detect a extreme right point. For this I use bounding box (`viewer.getBoundingBoxGeo()`), I have X,Y and Z min and max. Then (and I have a problem) I would be detect the left perpendicular point. In this case, bounding box only works if rectangular table is matched with spatial coordinates of bounding box. I think...

Comment: Correct... You can get a maximum width by computing the squared-distances between every pair ( x, z ) of points and selecting the square-root of the maximum value... The max height is just the largest y-coord of the points. (y is up in three.js).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it, but I have understand you, have I Xmax/min and Zmax/min  and apply squared-distances between them? Another question,  how do I read matrix of points? I have the pointcloud in a variable "PointCloudOctree" type: "Object 3D". Thanks for your speedy answer!

Comment: (1) `distanceSquared = ( v1.x - v2.x ) * ( v1.x - v2.x ) + ( v1.z - v2.z ) * ( v1.z - v2.z );` Do that for every pair of points in the point cloud. Remember the maximum distanceSquared. Then take the square root of the result. (2) Sorry, I cant give you a tutorial. You will have to figure out how the access the data yourself.

Comment: @WestLangley You could have posted that last comment as an answer so the question can be closed :D

Comment: Yes, a lot of thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a maximum width by computing the squared-distances between every pair ( x, z ) of points in your point cloud

```
distanceSquared = ( v1.x - v2.x ) * ( v1.x - v2.x ) + ( v1.z - v2.z ) * ( v1.z - v2.z );
```

and then selecting the square-root of the maximum value.

The maximum height is just the largest y-coordinate of the points.

Comment: Yes, but in your example, we know all points coordinates , 'v1' and 'v2'. In my real process, all point clouds are different. I mean, I don't know any point, there is some function in Three.js or Potree that let obtain points coordinates in function of one condition? P.e.: if 'v1.y = v2.y = 0' lets to obtain the points in extremes ('v1.x', 'v1.z' and 'v2.x', 'v2.z').

Comment: Loop through your points and only compute the distance for the subset of point pairs for which `v1.y = v2.y = 0`.